# Interrupt cin >> str while loop

Tags: c++

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it shows:

```
process finished with exit code 0
```

And, the code following the loop will never be executed (the `cout` sentence). What if I want to continue execution of this program?

```
string str;
while(cin >> str);
cout << "outside of the loop";
return 0
```

Environment: CLion for Linux.

Comment: Than handle EOF (ctrl-d).

Comment: Are you *sure*? You maybe just don't have time to see it? Or perhaps you miss it because it's not on its own line? Try adding another input (using e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) after the output, or adding a trailing newline.

Comment: Try `"outside of the loop\n"`.

Comment: @Some _"Try adding another input ..."_ Wouldn't this require to `clear()` `cin`?

Comment: Run your program from the command line.

Comment: Works fine when I running it from command line. Compiler `GCC 4.8.5`.

Comment: @user0042 Yes it would.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug of Clion because when I try to run the on Terminal, it works like a charm. Alternatively, I prefer `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout`, - it works on both Clion and Terminal as well.

[image]

Comment: The buffer will be flushed when the program returns from main.

Comment: It was my mistake. I've edited. @BenjaminLindley